# Showing differentiability of the dot product

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as the dot product $f(a,b) = a \cdot b$. During the course of the proof, I have reduced the expression of the argument in the limit definition of differentiability to the following:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\left|{f(a+h_1, b + h_2}) - f(a,b) - Df(a,b)(h_1,h_2)\right|}{\|h\|}
&= \frac{\left|h_1 \cdot h_2 \right|}{||h||}\\
&\leq \frac{\|h_1|| \|h_2||}{\|h\|}
\end{align*}
The goal is to show that the LHS is bounded by something that converges to $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$. However, I can't figure out how to further bound the inequality, or how to show that the presented inequality tends toward $0$. Also, since $h \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is considered a 2-tuple of vectors, how does one interpret the norm of $h$ in the denominator?

Comment: Can you show that $|h_1 \cdot h_2| \leq \|h_1\|^2 + \|h_2\|^2$? Also, $\|h\| = \|(h_1,h_2)\|$ is just another vector on $2n$ coordinates.

Comment: @Corrêa If that inequality is shown, I'm still unsure about dealing with $\|h\|$ in the denominator. We would have $\frac{\|h_1\|^2 + \|h_2\|^2}{\|h\|}$ right?

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$h_1 = (h_{1,1},...,h_{1,n})$$
and
$$h_2 = (h_{2,1},...,h_{2,n}).$$
Thus,
$$\|(h_1,h_2)\|^2 = \left(\sqrt{h_{1,1}^2 + \cdots + h_{1,n}^2 + h_{2,1}^2 + \cdots + h_{2,n}^2}\right)^2 = \|h_1\|^2 + \|h_2\|^2,$$
from where
$$\frac{\|h_1\|^2 + \|h_2\|^2}{\|(h_1,h_2)\|} = \|(h_1,h_2)\|.$$

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you.